# Pytest: Mock every invocation of a method for an entire test module?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have a Python class, and for one of the methods of the class, I want every test that calls the method to call a mocked version of the method. For example, if I have this class:

```
class TestClass:
    def func():
       print("func")
```

And these tests (using pytest):

```
def test_1():
    myTestObj1 = TestClass()
    myTestObj1.func()

def test_2():
    myTestObj2 = TestClass()
    myTestObj2.func()
```

How can I mock this class so that both test cases call a version of `func` that does nothing, while not affecting any of the other methods of `TestClass`?

Answer (score 0):

You can patch `func` using `pytest-mock` from inside the test.

https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
import pytest

class TestClass:
    def func(self):
       return "Func"

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def class_fixture():
    yield TestClass()       

def test_1(class_fixture, mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(TestClass, "func", return_value = None)
    assert class_fixture.func() == None

def test_2(class_fixture):
    assert class_fixture.func() == "Func"
```